# Declaring variables on Google sheet script editor using let

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Whe I try to initialize variable using `let` I get prompted by this error: Missing ; before statement.

How to declare variables using `let` on Google sheet Script editor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`let` was added from ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). But, unfortunately, Google Apps Script doesn't support ES6 yet. So when `let` is used in the script editor, in the current stage, the error occurs.

A lot of users want for ES6 to be added to Google Apps Script, It's on the feature requests, however, no progress seems to have been made.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764074

#### Reference :

- [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript)
- [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)
- [Basic JavaScript features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

#### Updated at February 12, 2020

Finally, the V8 Runtime has already been added to Google Apps Script. By this, `let` can be used in Google Apps Script.

Please check [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime).

Comment: I see, that enlightens me. Thank you.

Comment: @Herbert John Verdida Welcome. I also want ES6 for GAS.

Comment: i see here, the latest Apps Script is based on JavaScript 1.6, plus a few features from 1.7 and 1.8 [HERE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)

Comment: I have let in all my code but today I got this error. It disappears when I switch to var. August 16 2021 ???? Did something slip?

Comment: Today variables declared with const get this error TypeError: redeclaration of const presTemplateUrl. WHAT HAS HAPPENED? Is it permanent?